# .NET Framework version

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

I have an app that was created using .net Framework 3.5.  However, I now need to change this to use the 2.0 Framework, as it needs to be distributed to a Windows 2000 machine.  Will simply changing the Application Target Framework on the project properties be sufficient to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you don't use any .NET 3.5 specific stuff.

Then it won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Change the target framework and do a recompile. You will probably also change your references to .Net 2.0 system assemblies. 
As long as you don't use any new features this should be sufficient.